# How to retrieve activities list from Google+ when user logged in

Tags: google-plus

Im trying to get my activity list when i sign into my googleplus account. I need the code in php. I tried getting all my profile information, but cannot able to fetch my activity list.

I used the request https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/activityId/people/collection

and scopes.

Please guide me how to fetch the activity list in PHP code.

```
var request = gapi.client.plus.activities.list({ 'userId' : 'me', 'collection' : 'public' }); request.execute(function(resp) {
    var numItems = resp.items.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        console.log('ID: ' + resp.items[i].id + ' Content: ' + resp.items[i].object.content);
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to be more specific and show what code you are using and what errors you are getting.

Comment: How to execute the javascript code

Comment: var request = gapi.client.plus.activities.list({
  'userId' : 'me',
  'collection' : 'public'
});

request.execute(function(resp) {
  var numItems = resp.items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    console.log('ID: ' + resp.items[i].id + ' Content: ' +
      resp.items[i].object.content);
  }
});

Comment: Please update your question to be more specific. I can't tell if you want PHP or JS help and you need to include the specific errors you are getting and what you have tried.